# make file for Java/Linux

Tags: java, linux, makefile

I have the following makefile after running it once I make some changes to the makefile and now when I run it I get a "make: Nothing to be done for `default'."  How can I force it to rebuild?  I execute "make" and also "make clean" and I still get the error message when I type "make".

Also, how do I get the log4.properties file which is in the src directory to be copied over to the target directory (in the make file and on the command line: javac -classpath src:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar src/*.java -d bin)?

```
#
# define compiler and compiler flag variables
#

JFLAGS = -g -cp .:src:lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar
JC = javac


#
# Clear any default targets for building .class files from .java files; we 
# will provide our own target entry to do this in this makefile.
# make has a set of default targets for different suffixes (like .c.o) 
# Currently, clearing the default for .java.class is not necessary since 
# make does not have a definition for this target, but later versions of 
# make may, so it doesn't hurt to make sure that we clear any default 
# definitions for these
#

.SUFFIXES: .java .class


#
# Here is our target entry for creating .class files from .java files 
# This is a target entry that uses the suffix rule syntax:
#   DSTS:
#       rule
#  'TS' is the suffix of the target file, 'DS' is the suffix of the dependency 
#  file, and 'rule'  is the rule for building a target  
# '$*' is a built-in macro that gets the basename of the current target 
# Remember that there must be a  before the command line ('rule') 
#

.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java


#
# CLASSES is a macro consisting of 4 words (one for each java source file)
#

CLASSES = \
    src/MatrixDriver.java \
    src/ConcreteMatrix.java \
    src/Matrix.java \
    src/Submatrix.java 


#
# the default make target entry
#

default: classes


#
# This target entry uses Suffix Replacement within a macro: 
# $(name:string1=string2)
#   In the words in the macro named 'name' replace 'string1' with 'string2'
# Below we are replacing the suffix .java of all words in the macro CLASSES 
# with the .class suffix
#

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)


#
# RM is a predefined macro in make (RM = rm -f)
#

clean: FORCE
    $(RM) *.class

FORCE:
```

Comment: I added the -d bin for the output directory but just took it out.  I'm still getting the make: Nothing to be done for `default'.

Comment: Going a bit off-topic, but you may want to look at build tools that are more targeted towards Java, e.g. Ant or Maven. Being able to put `**/*.jar` on the classpath becomes convenient very quickly once you get more than a few dependencies.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in on Maven -- definitely the way to go for your sanity's sake, imo...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that this:

```
.java.class:
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
%.class: %.java
    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $^
```

Comment: When I make that change I get this: "makefile:34: *** target pattern contains no `%'.  Stop."

Answer (score 0):

I did not read your Makefile carefully and I do not consider myself a make expert
but

1. there does not seem to be any dependency on the Makefile itself
2. all you changed is the Makefile

leads me to think that the correct behavior is exactly what you described.  Perhaps you can add a dependency to the Makefile.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no file or directory called classes.  Make could then assume nothing more to do.