# No rule to make target makefile

Tags: java, makefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [make file for Java/Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935635/make-file-for-java-linux)

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class:    $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES =   pprint.java ARPModule.java  EthernetModule.java IPModule.java   FrameModule.java 

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean:  $(RM) *.class
```

Keep getting this error:

> No rule to make target `pprint.class', needed by `classes'.  Stop.

I tried clearing all my spaces and putting tabs but no go.

Comment: Fixed it. It was a tab problem. Sometimes the smallest things can drive you up the wall. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the commands for the `.java.class` rule on a separate line:

```
.java.class:
        $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java
```

Or, if you are desparate for vertical space, you can put them on the same line after a semi-colon:

```
.java.class: ; $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java
```