# Error from the java makefile

Tags: java, makefile

I'm trying to compile java files with make.

My `Makefile` produces the following output when I run `make`.

```
make: *** No rule to make target `file1.class', needed by `classes'.  Stop.
```

What's causing this error?
Here is my original `Makefile`

```
JFLAGS = -g
JC = javac
.SUFFIXES: .java .class
.java.class: $(JC) $(JFLAGS) $*.java

CLASSES = \
        file1.java \
        file2.java \
        file3.java \
        file4.java \
        main.java

default: classes

classes: $(CLASSES:.java=.class)

clean: $(RM) *.class
```

Comment: Look here :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050481/no-rule-to-make-target-makefile

Comment: possible duplicate of [make file for Java/Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935635/make-file-for-java-linux)

Comment: *Why* are you trying to use `make` with Java? There are much better tools.